# How to remove the page alias from url with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created my own cms and i find the following issue. The pages links show as this:

https://www.example.com/page/contact-us

I want them to show as this, by removing the **page** alias:

https://www.example.com/contact-us

My Htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([\s\S]*)$ single-page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

I have tried this but doesn't work for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page/single-page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page/single-page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

This won't work because it is forwarding all URIs to `/page/` directory which obvious doesn't exist.

You should be using this rule:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ single-page.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi sir, This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895366/how-to-use-awk-to-continuously-output-lines-from-a-file/63895525#63895525 got deleted, but I don't think it should be deleted, could you please take a look, what you feel on it, cheers.